# Tomcat File Upload with Email attachment fails - Permission Denied

Tags: java, file, tomcat, upload, permissions

the code that I have used to work before, but started to fail now, my guess would be something was changed on the server, maybe permissions or something else. I need to figure out what it might be in order to fix.

Basically I have:

1. POST request that sends file to the server
2. File is send as attachment via email

Here is the code that prepares Mimeparts

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();        
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

//parse request
List<?> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

HashMap<String, FileItem> form = new HashMap<String, FileItem>(); 

Iterator<?> iterator = items.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();           
    form.put(item.getFieldName(), item);
}


//handle attachment
if(form.containsKey("uploaded_file"))
{
    FileItem fileItem = form.get("uploaded_file");
    String fileName = fileItem.getName();
  File f = new File(fileName);
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = fileItem.getInputStream();

        OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
            out.write(buf,0,len);

        out.close();
        inputStream.close();

    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
    attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(f)));
    attachment.setFileName(fileName);
}



//below I use a javax.mail.Transport to send it via email      
//mimeparts : new MimeBodyPart[]{attachment}
```

The code used to work ok, just started to throw this exception:

```
    javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
      nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: uploaded_file_name.zip (Permission denied)
        com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1141)
        javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
        javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

Comment: Check directory write permission. I guess you are storing files under webapp.

Comment: Can u please specify which directory exactly I have to check ? I do not save the file locally, I guess it just goes to some temp folder ?

Comment: System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") is this the right folder ? If yes, what permission do I have to set in order for email to pick up attachments from there ?